# Construction some special sequence of events

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I am ask to get a random variable $X\ge 0$ on $(\Omega,\mathbf F,P)$ such that $\mathbf E(X)=\infty$ and their exist sequence $\{A_k\}\subset \mathbf F$ such that $P(A_k)\rightarrow 0$ as $k\rightarrow \infty$ and $\mathbf E(X \chi_{A_k})$ is bounded away from zero.

I am not getting any idea about how to approach it. Any type of help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are there any hypothesis on the measure space? I doubt such an $X$ exists in every possible case (like the finite ones).

Comment: @Leo163 yes you are given the probability measure

Comment: Then it would be useful to know it I guess.

Comment: Just take $A_k = \{X\ge k\}$. This should satisfy your requirements.

Comment: @Will Nelson what probability measure will you define then

Comment: @yash Anything you want. If $X$ is a random variable as you've defined, then $E(X \chi_{X>k}) = \infty$ for all $k$. And $P(X>k)\downarrow 0$ as $k\to \infty$, as long as $P(X=\infty)=0$ (which is a conventional, unstated assumption).

Answer (score 0):

One of the solution will be :
$\Omega=(0,1) , F=\mathbf B[(0,1)]$ and $P$ to be  lebesgue measure on $\mathbb R$ and the random variable X defined as $X(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ consider $A_k=(\frac{1}{2^{k+1}},\frac{1}{2^k})$ then $P(A_k)\rightarrow 0$ as $k\rightarrow \infty$ and probability density function($f_X$) of X is given by $$f_X(x)=\begin{cases} 0& if\ x\le1\\\frac{1}{x^2}&if\ x>1\end{cases}$$ then $E(X)=\int\limits_{1}^{\infty}xf_X(x)\ dx=\infty$ but $E[X\ \chi_{A_k}]=\int\limits_{A_k}X\ dP\ge2^kP(A_k)=\frac{1}{2}$